# Running VB Script file with arguments

Tags: command-line, vbscript, command-line-arguments

I have to run a VB script which has 2 arguments. So I am running a command below.

```
Delete_Dummy1.vb
s C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv C:\Users\c6342\Deskto
p\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt
```

```vb
**VB Script Sample - not working:** 
**sourceloc** = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
**destloc** = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
Dim objFSO, dataArray, clippedArray()
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("**sourceloc**")
Set newFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("**destloc**")
```

It throws the error as **file not found.** But if I hard code the sourceloc and destloc and remove the arguments it is working fine. it is throwing error only when i am using arguments.

```
**Working VB Script sample:**
Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv")
Set newFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt")
```

This works fine. But as per my project requirement, I cant hard code these file locations. I can pass as parameters from command.

Comment: Sorry Please ignore ** in the code snippets. I just highlighted important things with **.

Comment: You need to wrap the arguments with spaces in with double quotes *(`"`)*.

Comment: I tried with double quotes also. But anyways there are no spaces in my source and destination file locations.

Comment: I understand you saying enclosing each value in quotes didn't work? Check out [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35630022/692942) I go into a bit more detail about how the space is being interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [length discussion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629862/running-vb-script-file-with-arguments/35630022?noredirect=1#comment58946828_35630022) think it will be best to just update my answer.

The reason for the Arguments not working is you never pass them to the `OpenTextFile()` and `CreateTextFile()` methods. Instead you are passing literal strings containing the variable name instead of the actual variables.

```
sourceloc = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
destloc = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

Dim objFSO, dataArray, clippedArray()
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Pass the variables not a string literal
Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sourceloc)
Set newFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(destloc)
```

As it stands VBScript keeps trying to locate a file called `sourceloc` and `destloc` instead of the actual file names from the passed Arguments collection. Which is what likely causes the

> Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error: File Not Found

---

***Note:*** Below is based on [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35629862/2) which has since been revised.

---

This comes down to how you are passing the arguments to the script, any spaces in the values will be treated as new arguments. At the moment this is how the arguments are passed;

```
0. C:\Users\enter
1. code
2. herec6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv
3. C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt
```

I'm sure this isn't what you expect. To avoid this enclose each argument in double quotes *(`"..."`)*.

```
Delete_Dummy1.vbs "C:\Users\enter code herec6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv" "C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt"
```

That way you get more what you expected

```
0. C:\Users\enter code herec6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv
1. C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt
```

Comment: Delete_Dummy1.vbs "C:\Users\chandu\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv" "C:\Users\chandu\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt"
I tried this. but still not working.

Comment: @chandrasekhar I can only go off what you posted, either way using double quotes is always a good idea to avoid these types of problems. I'm not sure what posting that line as a comment accomplishes without an explanation? This is what you initially posted `Delete_Dummy1.vb
s C:\Users\enter code herec6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv C:\Users\c6342\Deskto
p\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt`. I'm guessing the `enter code herec6342` was a typo, that probably caused your original `File Not Found` error.

Comment: Sorry. my user name is c6342. after posting my question, stackoverflow automatically converted c6342 into enter code herec6342. that's why i removed that code and replaced with chandu while commenting to avoid confusion.

Comment: @chandrasekhar If you want to do that you would be better [editing the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35629862/edit).

Comment: I edited the question and running the below command. is there any mistake in the below command?
Delete_Dummy1.vbs "C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml.csv" "C:\Users\c6342\Desktop\XML_to_CSV\Temp_Files\xml1.txt"

Comment: @chandrasekhar Not that I can see. Do those two files definitely exist and you have permission to access them? Try running the script using `cscript.exe` through an elevated command prompt. I think the arguments are being passed correctly so it must be to do with how the script is run.

Comment: Those files exist and it is working when I remove the arguments in vb script and replace with these file locations. But I am getting this error only when I am passing values through arguments. Also I am getting the error in the line 10 in vb script which is the source file location argument.
I have access to run all the commands.

Comment: @chandrasekhar The code example in the question isn't very clear, looks like you are passing a string `"**sourceloc**"` instead of the actual variable  you assign the `Argument` to. Can you maybe tidy up the code example a bit it's hard to help when the example code isn't right.

Comment: sourceloc is the argument which I created in the VB script. Same I am using here. Please see the code snippt below.

sourceloc = WScript.Arguments.Item(0) -- creating argument sourceloc.
Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sourceloc") -- Assigning this argument value to a variable oTextStream.

Comment: @chandrasekhar Nope that's where you are going wrong what you are actual assigning to `objFSO.OpenTextFile()` is  a string that evaluates to the literal `sourceloc`, so VBScript can't find a source file called `sourceloc`, instead pass the actual variable as the parameter for the method - `objFSO.OpenTextFile(sourceloc)`.

Comment: I tried to assign arguments values to variables below. Is this what you are asking me to do?

sourceloc = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
destloc = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

Dim objFSO, dataArray, clippedArray()
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim source, dest
Set source = sourceloc
Set dest = destloc

Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("source")
Set newFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("dest")

Comment: @chandrasekhar Updated my answer hopefully that will explain better then the comments can.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart. It works... Thanks for your time and help.